# Returning a BLOB (Binary Large Object) using nest/graphql

Tags: graphql, nest

I have a Binary Large Object (BLOB) field in a MYSQL database which contains encrypted data.

How do I return this encrypted data with nest/graphQL? Is there a field type that will return this to the client (in my case another node server)?

```js
@Field(type => ????)
@Column("blob", { name: "encrypted_data", nullable: true })
encryptedData: Buffer | null;
```